# Trying to upgrade extension with MySQL queries update

Tags: php, upgrade

Here is my: mysql4-install-1.1.php:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("order", "my_custom_input_field_one", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field_one", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->endSetup();
```

And then i've created an upgrade file: mysql4-upgrade-1.1-1.2.php :

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute("order", "my_custom_input_field_two", array("type"=>"text"));
$installer->addAttribute("quote", "my_custom_input_field_two", array("type"=>"text"));  
$installer->endSetup();
```

When the extension was created the `my_custom_input_field_one` was created. Then i have the need to created second column called `my_custom_input_field_two` so i've created an upgrade file.

After i created the upgrade file i changed my config.xml from:

```
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
    </modules>
```

to:

```
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </VivasIndustries_Vshippingone>
    </modules>
```

After that i've flushed the cache but the second column was not created.
Where is my mistake and how can i create this second column with the upgrade file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it tell you the current version of the module is in the core_resource table?

Comment: It still sais: 1.1

Comment: If it's still 1.1, then Magento has not read your config.xml file, try your luck again with caching.

Comment: Cleared it like 3000 times for now, and nothing changed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an upgrade script, you need to use the following name pattern upgrade-{old-version-number}-{new-version-number}.php

Rename your upgrade script file

From

```
 mysql4-upgrade-1.1-1.2.php
```

To

```
  upgrade-1.1-1.2.php
```